# Symfony 2 : Form entity field add "data-*" attribute on each radio input

Tags: html, forms, symfony

I have a form with a field of type "entity" displaying radio fields :

```
->add(
            'membership',
            'entity',
              array(
                'class' => 'Comiti\UserBundle\Entity\Membership',
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => false,
                'label' => false,
                'empty_value' => 'Aucune adhésion',
                'query_builder' => function (MembershipRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('membership')
                        ->where('membership.club = :club')
                        ->setParameter('club', $this->authentication_service->getCurrentClub())
                        ->orderBy('membership.name', 'ASC')
                    ;
                }, 
            )
        )
```

I am adding radio fields in my view like that :

```
{{ form_row(form.membership) }}
```

Rendering something like that in html:

```html
<input type= "radio" name="membership" value="1">
<input type= "radio" name="membership" value="2">
<input type= "radio" name="membership" value="3">
```

I would like to add "data-price" to each input :

```html
<input type= "radio" name="membership" data-price="20" value="1">
<input type= "radio" name="membership" data-price="10" value="2">
<input type= "radio" name="membership" data-price="15" value="3">
```

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 7):

If you are on symfony >= 2.7 you can use "choice_attr"

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#choice-attr

```
$builder->add('attending', 'choice', array(
    'choices' => array(
        'Yes' => true,
        'No' => false,
        'Maybe' => null,
    ),
    'choices_as_values' => true,
    'choice_attr' => function($val, $key, $index) {
        // adds a class like attending_yes, attending_no, etc
        return ['class' => 'attending_'.strtolower($key)];
    },
));
```

Comment: I am on 2.6.6 unfortunately

Comment: In this case you can maybe create an array in your controller with your data-price values, send it to your Twig and add your data-price in your input with javascript ...

Answer (score -1):

Think you are looking for this:

```
form = $this->createFormBuilder($someObj)
        ->add('myInput', 'text', array(
             'attr' => array('myAttr' => 'myValue')
        )
        ->getForm();
```

docs are here: 
http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/forms/types/field.html

Comment: Not really, i know the attr option but how to display it on each radio input of my entity field